# Importing module with custom lookup

Tags: python, import

I have some problems with my project structure.
Because of historical reasons project looks like this:

```
Source/
    __init__.py
    module1/
        __init__.py
        script1.py
    module2/
        __init__.py
        script2.py
```

and in production it deploys like this

```
server/
    __init__.py
    module1/
        __init__.py
        script1.py
    module2/
        __init__.py
        script2.py
```

The problem is that `script2.py` has such imports:

```
from server.module1.script1 import something
```

Is it possible to say python to search `server.***` not in `server/***` but in `Source/***`?

Right now I made this with symlinks, but it looks ugly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always add keys to the `sys.modules` dictionary; these act as aliases for the module:

```
import sys

try:
    import server
except ImportError:
    import Source
    sys.modules['server'] = Source
```

Once `server` is an entry in `sys.modules`, any sub-modules and packages will be found as well as the `server` entry will be used as a starting point for further imports.

Comment: What about submodules? Will this enable such import? `from server.module1.script1 import something`

Comment: @akaRem: My quick tests show that that works, yes. Python imports `module1` based on the `sys.modules['server'].__file__` information, then imports `script1` based on `sys.modules['server.module1']` as that now exists as well.